# Add some manufacturer data into my advertising BLE c#

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I created a C# server that have custom characteristics and I advertise it, it work perfectly fine but I want to add  manufacturer data into the Advertisement. How can I do that ?

Here is my code to create the BLE server where can I add the Manufacturer Data ?

```
public async void CreateBluetoothServer()
       {
            notifyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            notifyTimer.Tick += NotifyTimer_Tick;
            Guid Batt = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");
            GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(Batt);

            if (result.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
            {
                serviceProvider = result.ServiceProvider;
            }

            Guid Batt2 = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002");
            GattLocalCharacteristicParameters ReadParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
            {
                CharacteristicProperties = (GattCharacteristicProperties.Read),
            };
            GattLocalCharacteristicResult characteristicResult = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(Batt2, ReadParameters);//temp
            if (characteristicResult.Error != BluetoothError.Success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(result.Error.ToString());
                return;
            }
            _readCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
            _readCharacteristic.ReadRequested += ReadCharacteristic_ReadRequested_SendRandomString;

            Guid Batt3 = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003");
            GattLocalCharacteristicParameters WriteParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
            {
                CharacteristicProperties = (GattCharacteristicProperties.Write),
            };
            characteristicResult = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(Batt3, WriteParameters);//temp
            if (characteristicResult.Error != BluetoothError.Success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(result.Error.ToString());
                return;
            }
            _writeCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
            _writeCharacteristic.WriteRequested += WriteCharacteristic_WriteRequested;

            Guid Batt4 = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004");
            GattLocalCharacteristicParameters NotifyParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
            {
                CharacteristicProperties = (GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify),

            };
            characteristicResult = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(Batt4, NotifyParameters);//temp
            if (characteristicResult.Error != BluetoothError.Success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(result.Error.ToString());
                return;
            }
            _notifyCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
            _notifyCharacteristic.SubscribedClientsChanged += SubscribedClientsChanged;

            byte[] value = new byte[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x20, 0x21 };
            var constantParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
            {
                CharacteristicProperties = (GattCharacteristicProperties.Read),
                StaticValue = value.AsBuffer(),
                ReadProtectionLevel = GattProtectionLevel.Plain,
            };

            Guid Batt5 = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005");
            var characteristicResultT = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(Batt5, constantParameters);
            if (characteristicResultT.Error != BluetoothError.Success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(result.Error.ToString());
                return;
            }

            advParameters = new GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters
            {
                IsDiscoverable = true,
                IsConnectable = true//mettre a false
            };
        }
```

i can't validate if it's mostly code so i write some text
can i validate ?

Comment: You should use BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher class to publish custom advertisements (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementpublisher)